# Spring Web MVC Tiles extends from the same definition

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I am trying to create a Spring MVC program using tiles.

tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition" template="/template/mainTemplate.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Piranha"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/template/header.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="content" value=""></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/template/footer.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>

    <definition name="index" extends="base.defnition">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/view/index.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>
    <definition name="searched" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/view/searched.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

When I visit this url `http://localhost:8080/myProject/search`, I get this error

Error

```
message Could not resolve view with name 'searched' in servlet with name 'welcome'

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'searched' in servlet with name 'welcome'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1227)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

When I remove this code from tiles.xml, then it works fine

```
<definition name="index" extends="base.defnition">
      <put-attribute name="content" value="/view/index.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>
```

What is wrong with `tiles.xml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

It is a simple typo

you have written `base.defnition`

change that to `base.definition`

The corrected code below.

```
<definition name="index" extends="base.definition">
      <put-attribute name="content" value="/view/index.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>
```